# How to "fetch" in react

Tags: reactjs

I try to read data from two places: "/api/testimonial" and "/api/information"
 for first one (/api/testimonial) I write this code and it correctly works

```
    export default class Testimonials extends React.Component {
      constructor(){
        super();
            this.state ={
              customers:[]
            }
          }
          componentDidMount(){
            fetch('/api/testimonial')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(customers => this.setState({customers},() => console.log('customers fetched..', 
    customers)));
          }
      render() {
        return (
```

But I also need read some information from "/api/information". How can I fetch that two data at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) like this:

```
componentDidMount(){
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const [customers, informations] = await Promise.all([
      fetch('/api/testimonial').then(res => res.json()),
      fetch('/api/informations').then(res => res.json())
    ]);
    console.log('customers fetched..', customers);
    console.log('informations fetched..', informations);
    this.setState({ customers, informations });
  }

  fetchData();
}
```

And here's an example of how to render `customers` and `informations` data:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {this.state.customers.length && this.state.customers.map(customer => <span>{customer.title}</span>)}
      </div>
      <div>
        {this.state.informations.length && this.state.informations.map(information => <span>{information.title}</span>)}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: In console.log I can see my data, but I have error like "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined"

Comment: and also I want understand how can I read fetched data in this case? ... When I fetched only "/api/estimonials" I use data in body in this way 
{this.state.customers && this.state.customers[0] && (
                  <span>{this.state.customers[0].title}</span>

Answer (score 2):

See if you can make use of promises,

```
Promise.all([
  fetch("http://localhost:3000/API1"),
  fetch("http://localhost:3000/API2"),
]).then(([results1, results2]) => {
  //Process results 
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: It's not working in that way. It's not show even console.log

Answer (score 0):

```
export default class Testimonials extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      customers: []
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    let [requests1, request2] = await Promise.all([
      fetch('/api/testimonial'),
      fetch('/api/information'),
    ]);

    requests1
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(customers => console.log(customers));

    requests2
     .then(res => res.json());
     .......
  }
}
```

---

Comment: In my case I don't use async